# Sample size calculation when no prior study has been carried out

Tags: sample-size

I am struggling to grasp a sample size for the correlational study I am planning. I am looking at essentially two measures of the same thing - one measured and one self ranked and I want to see if there is a relationship between the two. The participants will have their nutritional intake measured and then calculated as a percentage of their requirements. The participants will also self rank their perceived nutritional intake on a scale of 1-5 for a number of parameters and these will be summed to give an overall score. I want to compare the self ranking scores against the true measured intake to see if there is a relationship. However, I cannot find that anything like this has been done before which is where I am struggling with sample size. Any suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 4):

If there is no prior information then you should carefully consider the possibility that your research will be preliminary and exploratory rather than definitive and final. In such a case there is no need to perform a power analysis because no final decision should be made on the basis of the results. Instead, you should use the experience gained from the preliminary work to define testable hypotheses, to see where this area of research might fit into existing theory and then design experiments.

As long as you do not make any scientific inference on the basis of the results,you can simply gather data until a pattern of interest appears in the results.

I have written about the role of preliminary experiments and the appropriate data gathering and analysis procedures in my commentary on the ASA's position statement on P-values. See the 14th article here: http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/suppl/10.1080/00031305.2016.1154108?scroll=top

Comment: A pilot study is another possibility as it gives you an idea of the value of parameters you need to estimate.  Therefore you can plan your next study with an estimate of sample size.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I agree. However, I note that a pilot study designed to estimate statistical parameter values for sample size estimation might not serve very well to identify the most fruitful types of questions to ask of the data or to identify desirable changes to the design of the analysis or the study itself.